# AWS SNS Filter Policy to String match none of the elements in the array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I referred [Amazon SNS subscription filter policies documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/string-value-matching.html). There is something not clear to me if it is possible to do.

Suppose we have a message with attribute

```
labels: ["A", "B"]
```

Now a filter policy like this will match it

```
{
  labels": ["A", "C"]
}
```

But a filter policy like this will also match it

```
{
  labels": [{"anything-but": ["A", "C"]}]
}
```

because of `"B"`

What we are looking for is a way to create two policies that are mutually exclusive.

- If `A` or `C` are present then trigger Lambda1
- If none of `A` or `C` are present, then trigger Lambda2

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't seem possible. One workaround to achieve it is to use anything-but with a prefix. Like this:

```
{
  "labels": [
    {
      "anything-but": {
        "prefix": "someprefix-"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You have to change your first filter like this:

```
{
  labels": ["someprefix-A", "someprefix-C"]
}
```

Now labels: ["someprefix-A", "B"] will only match the first filter.

Comment: May I please know how you would implement the "anything-but" clause in yaml?   Please see my question   https://stackoverflow.com/q/76177642/1338998