# AWS Filter policy configuration for the “event” in order for it to Reject “open” event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, aws-lambda, yaml

Here is info about our technical development environment:

- .NET 6
- C# 10

I am working on .NET AWS Cloud application that contains:

- an AWS Lambda Function
- an SQS To SNS Subscription

YAML:

```
 SqsToSnsSubscription:

  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription 

  Properties:  

   Endpoint: !GetAtt eventCollectorSQS.Arn

   Protocol: sqs

   RawMessageDelivery: true

   TopicArn: 

     Fn::ImportValue: 

       !Sub '${SNSStackName}-ourapp-eventsns' 

   FilterPolicyScope: MessageBody 

   FilterPolicy:

      ApplicationKey: 

         - !Sub ${ApplicationKey}

      event: 

         - '{"anything-but": ["open"]}'
```

JSON:

> { "Records": [ { "messageId": "19dd0b57-b21e-4ac1-bd88-01bbb068cb78",
> "receiptHandle": "MessageReceiptHandle", "body":
> "{"Id_int":"0","event_id":"i0hlDACuS7iXNQsTWV7A8w","ApplicationKey":"OURAPP__AWS_PROD","message_id":"filter0532p1mdw1.17244.559EBD9A19.0","reason":"Invalid","Id_Guid":"9f569664-f081-44e0-a81b-034cad99e14c","event":"open","email":\nottosendtome@noemailACME.com,"smtp-id":\2.8cc5881b7d3041b9ae2f@watd003,"timestamp":1436466597}",
> "attributes": { "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1", "SentTimestamp":
> "1523232000000", "SenderId": "123456789012",
> "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1523232000001" },
> "messageAttributes": {}, "md5OfBody":
> "7b270e59b47ff90a553787216d55d91d", "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
> "eventSourceARN": "arn:{partition}:sqs:{region}:123456789012:MyQueue",
> "awsRegion": "{region}" } ] }

The filter policy configuration for the “event” does Not work.  The event key can be associated with anything except open

What should I change to the filter policy configuration for the “event” in order for it to Reject “open”  event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by removing the single quotes a that was around the filter policy expression:

> ```
> SqsToSnsSubscription:
>
>  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription 
>
>  Properties:  
>
>  Endpoint: !GetAtt eventCollectorSQS.Arn
>
>  Protocol: sqs
>
>  RawMessageDelivery: true
>
>  TopicArn: 
>
>    Fn::ImportValue: 
>
>      !Sub '${SNSStackName}-ourapp-eventsns' 
>
>  FilterPolicyScope: MessageBody 
>
>  FilterPolicy:
>
>     ApplicationKey: 
>
>        - !Sub ${ApplicationKey}
>
>     event: 
>
>        - {"anything-but": ["open"]}
> ```